# Stripe change subscription with dropdown rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, subscriptions

I'm trying to implement a way for stripe to change subscriptions. I'm getting a little confused with my code. Currently i have the following:

Subscription_controller

```
def changeSubscription
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @plan = params[:type]
    c = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripeCustomerId)
    c.update_subscription(:plan => @plan, :prorate => true)
  end
```

routes.rb

```
post 'subscribe/change/:type' => 'subscribe#changeSubscription'
```

and in my edit view i have this psuedocode i'd like help with getting working

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= collection_select(drop_down_of_subscription_types) %>
    <%= link_to "post request to 'subscribe#changeSubscription' with type sent" %>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are missing a form (<form></form> I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `submit_tag` to render a submit button for a form.

`link_to` and `button_to` will **not work**.